# Is this a bug in python's gmpy2?

Tags: python, gmpy

A simple floating-point addition x+y in with precision 4 (i.e. IEEE mantissa width 3), with 3 bits for exponent (`emax=3`, `emin=-4`) for `x = mpfr('0.75')`, `y = mpfr('0.03125')` incorrectly gives `mpfr('0.75')` as result when it should be `mpfr('0.8125')`. Note that `0.3125` is a subnormal number for this reduced precision format.

Edit: Terminal interaction extracted from link and included for future reference.

```
>>> "{0:.10Df}".format(mpfr('0.75')+mpfr('0.03125'))
'0.7500000000'
>>> get_context()
  context(precision=4, real_prec=Default, imag_prec=Default,
  round=RoundToNearest, real_round=Default, imag_round=Default,
  emax=3, emin=-4,
  subnormalize=True,
  trap_underflow=False, underflow=False,
  trap_overflow=False, overflow=False,
  trap_inexact=False, inexact=True,
  trap_invalid=False, invalid=False,
  trap_erange=False, erange=False,
  trap_divzero=False, divzero=False,
  trap_expbound=False,
  allow_complex=False)
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

I believe it is a bug with creating subnormals from a string. I think it is fixed in the development code but I won't be able to test until later. I'll update this answer later.

Update

The problem is not related to creating a subnormal from a string. In this case, the subnormal value is created properly. In gmpy2 2.0.x, there is a rare bug when converted a string to a subnormal. The simplest work-around is to convert the input to an `mpq` type first; i.e. `mpfr(mpq('0.03125'))`.

The actual problem is the default rounding mode. The intermediate sum is exactly halfway between two 4 bit values. The default rounding mode of `RoundToNearest` selects the rounded value with final bit of 0. If you change the rounding mode to `RoundUp`, you get the expected result.

```
>>> from gmpy2 import *
>>> ctx=context(emax=4, emin=-4, precision=4)
>>> set_context(ctx)
>>> a=mpfr('0.75')
>>> b=mpfr('0.03125')
>>> "{0:.10Df}".format(a+b)
'0.7500000000'
>>> get_context().round=RoundUp
>>> "{0:.10Df}".format(a+b)
'0.8125000000'
```

One last comment: the values of `precision`, `emax` and `emin` are slight different between the IEEE standards and the MPFR library. If `e` is the exponent size and `p` is the precision (in IEEE terms), then `precision` should be `p+1`,`emax` should be `2**(e-1)` and `emin` should be `4-emax-precision`. This doesn't impact your question since it only changes `emax`.

Comment: Thanks for the super prompt response. Can I download the development version you are referring to where the bug might have been fixed? Is it at its github [repository](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy)? If so, which revision should I check out?

Comment: Just grab the most recent version from github. It should work for testing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this so promptly. I am required to use RoundToNearest, so a different rounding mode is not an option for me. I tried the mentioned fix with mpq but it did n't work: gave 0.75 yet again. I'm using gmpy2-2.0.3. Thanks for pointing out the error in emax: can you mention the general formula to get emin for a general e, p (4 seems to be specific to my example?)?